# how to generate sequence number in plsql in a cyclic way

Tags: oracle, plsql, sequence

I want to generate sequence number  from 91 to 100 using oracle plsql code and if my sequence reaches 100 next value should be 91 again .

Please help

Comment: Alternatively use `select 91 + mod(rownum-1,10) seq from dual connect by level <=  some_limit_number`

Answer (score 2):

Ummm ... no. That's not a PL/SQL issue. You should generate a **sequence** that does what you described:

```
create sequence seq_ng minvalue 91 maxvalue 100 cycle nocache;
```

---

```
SQL> create sequence seq_ng minvalue 91 maxvalue 100 cycle nocache;

Sequence created.

SQL> select seq_ng.nextval from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
        91

SQL> select seq_ng.nextval from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
        92

<snip>

SQL> select seq_ng.nextval from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
       100

SQL> select seq_ng.nextval from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
        91              --> it starts over again

SQL>
```